# Change the color of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following function:

```
function red(opt) {
    var sqr;
    sqr="r"+parseInt(opt);
    hilight_css = {"background-color":"#f00"};
    $(#sqr).css(hilight_css);  
}
```

I call this function from another function

```
red(questions);
```

the variable `questions` has the value `1`.
The id of my div is `r1`.
When I use this code it does not work. Can anybody help fix this?

If I use `alert(sqr)` to show me the value of `sqr` it says `r1`
 but the color of the div doesn't change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass a string to the `$` function, like so:

```
$("#" + sqr).css(hilight_css);
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting obviously gives you a clue in OP's question. I wonder if it's just laziness or if he didn't even notice.

Answer (score 3):

Constantinius' answer is correct, but I wanted to point out that the code can be written more compact:

```
function red(opt) {
    $("#r"+opt).css("background-color", "#f00");
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, either you do css({"background-color":"#f00"}) or css("background-color", "#f00")

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
function red(opt)
        {
           var sqr;
           sqr="r"+parseInt(opt);
           hilight_css = {"background-color":"#f00"};
           $("#"+sqr).css(hilight_css); 
        }
```